# what does this inversed triangle stand for?

Tags: analysis, notation

Can someone show me the meaning of this symbol? I've googled but couldn't find it

[image]

Comment: [Nabla symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla_symbol).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called **nabla**, which is the name of the symbol but not it's meaning.

In Calculus, you can find it (alone) as an operator meaning "denotes the vector of partial derivatives":

$$\nabla = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\ \frac{\partial}{\partial y},\ \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)$$

If you are in three dimensions.

In your case, the $x$ subscripts indicates the only $x$ component of the gradient:

$$\nabla_x = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$

**More here**
[what does ∇ (upside down triangle) symbol mean in this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5076/what-does-)∇-upside-down-triangle-symbol-mean-in-this-problem?noredirect=1&lq=1